# Notation and multiplication of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, notation

I am having some trouble with notation and multiplication of a probability distribution.

Basically, I have a model that estimates the probability that debris will travel a distance $x$ using the Weibull density function:

$$\begin{aligned}
P[X=x] = \frac{\kappa}{\lambda} \biggl(\frac{x}{\lambda}\biggl)^{\kappa-1}e^{-(x / \lambda)^\kappa} &  & x \in (0,\infty)\\
\end{aligned}$$

The probability of exceeding a distance $x$ is modeled as the Weibull distribution function:

$$\begin{aligned}
P[X>x] = e^{-(x / \lambda)^\kappa} &  & x \in (0,\infty)\\
\end{aligned}$$

There is an object located between a distance of $0$ and $s$, and the location of the object is independent of $x$. What is the probability that the object will be hit by the debris?

I think that this is the answer:

\begin{equation}
 P[HIT ] =
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{x}{s} e^{-(x / \lambda)^\kappa} & 0<x \leq s \\
    e^{-(x / \lambda)^\kappa} &  x > s
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

However, I can't completely convince myself it is correct, because I am unsure of how to write the notation for the middle step.

How would I write a probability equation for of the object being a distance less than $x$? (assuming that the location is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $s$)

I have been overthinking this problem for a while, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the location of the object uniformly distributed on $[0,s]$?

Comment: Yes. I will add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition on the location of the object: if $H$ is the event that the object is hit by the debris, then
$$P(H) = \int_0^s \frac{1}{s} P(H | t) dt $$
where $P(H|t)$ is the probability that there is a hit given that the object is at location $t$. Then
$$P(H|t) = P(X > t)$$
And you know $P(X > t)$ from above. Can you solve that integral now?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I spent some time trying to digest what you were saying and want to clarify a few things. First, the object will be hit if X>t. So shouldn't P(H|t) = P(X>t)? Second, is the first formula supposed to include the probability density function for a uniform distribution? Therefore, should it be 1/s rather than 1/t? Otherwise can you please explain the 1/t?

Comment: You are right... I've made edits to incorporate these changes. Does everything look good now?